# Partitioning for <tablename> is not found the table might be not partitioned

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I'm working on a project for creating a zabbix server with a database so I want to partition the database tables for the zabbix server with an external script from the zabbix website but I'm facing this problem:

```
Oct 24 09:27:01 itit_mdbsrv01 mysql_zbx_part[31702]: Partitioning for "history_str" is not found! The table might be not partitioned.
```

and this is the script I'm running on the database server

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
use Sys::Syslog qw(:standard :macros);
use DateTime;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

openlog("mysql_zbx_part", "ndelay,pid", LOG_LOCAL0);

my $db_schema = 'yousif';
my $dsn = 'DBI:mysql:'.$db_schema.':mysql_socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock';
my $db_user_name = 'yousif';
my $db_password = 'LiL132LiL';
my $tables = {  'history' => { 'period' => 'day', 'keep_history' => '30'},
        'history_log' => { 'period' => 'day', 'keep_history' => '30'},
        'history_str' => { 'period' => 'day', 'keep_history' => '30'},
        'history_text' => { 'period' => 'day', 'keep_history' => '30'},
        'history_uint' => { 'period' => 'day', 'keep_history' => '30'},
        'trends' => { 'period' => 'month', 'keep_history' => '2'},
        'trends_uint' => { 'period' => 'month', 'keep_history' => '2'},

# comment next 5 lines if you partition zabbix database starting from 2.2
# they usually used for zabbix database before 2.2

        'acknowledges' => { 'period' => 'month', 'keep_history' => '23'},
        'alerts' => { 'period' => 'month', 'keep_history' => '6'},
        'auditlog' => { 'period' => 'month', 'keep_history' => '24'},
        'events' => { 'period' => 'month', 'keep_history' => '12'},
        'service_alarms' => { 'period' => 'month', 'keep_history' => '6'},
        };
my $amount_partitions = 10;

my $curr_tz = 'Europe/London';

my $part_tables;

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user_name, $db_password);

unless ( check_have_partition() ) {
    print "Your installation of MySQL does not support table partitioning.\n";
    syslog(LOG_CRIT, 'Your installation of MySQL does not support table partitioning.');
    exit 1;
}

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT table_name, partition_name, lower(partition_method) as partition_method,
                    rtrim(ltrim(partition_expression)) as partition_expression,
                    partition_description, table_rows
                FROM information_schema.partitions
                WHERE partition_name IS NOT NULL AND table_schema = ?});
$sth->execute($db_schema);

while (my $row =  $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    $part_tables->{$row->{'table_name'}}->{$row->{'partition_name'}} = $row;
}

$sth->finish();

foreach my $key (sort keys %{$tables}) {
    unless (defined($part_tables->{$key})) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, 'Partitioning for "'.$key.'" is not found! The table might be not partitioned.');
        next;
    }

    create_next_partition($key, $part_tables->{$key}, $tables->{$key}->{'period'});
    remove_old_partitions($key, $part_tables->{$key}, $tables->{$key}->{'period'}, $tables->{$key}->{'keep_history'})
}

delete_old_data();

$dbh->disconnect();

sub check_have_partition {
    my $result = 0;
# MySQL 5.5
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name = 'have_partitioning'});
# MySQL 5.6
    #my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT plugin_status FROM information_schema.plugins WHERE plugin_name = 'partition'});

    $sth->execute();

    my $row = $sth->fetchrow_array();

    $sth->finish();

# MySQL 5.5
    return 1 if $row eq 'YES';
# MySQL 5.6
    #return 1 if $row eq 'ACTIVE';
}

sub create_next_partition {
    my $table_name = shift;
    my $table_part = shift;
    my $period = shift;

    for (my $curr_part = 0; $curr_part < $amount_partitions; $curr_part++) {
        my $next_name = name_next_part($tables->{$table_name}->{'period'}, $curr_part);
        my $found = 0;

        foreach my $partition (sort keys %{$table_part}) {
            if ($next_name eq $partition) {
                syslog(LOG_INFO, "Next partition for $table_name table has already been created. It is $next_name");
                $found = 1;
            }
        }

        if ( $found == 0 ) {
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "Creating a partition for $table_name table ($next_name)");
            my $query = 'ALTER TABLE '."$db_schema.$table_name".' ADD PARTITION (PARTITION '.$next_name.
                        ' VALUES less than (UNIX_TIMESTAMP("'.date_next_part($tables->{$table_name}->{'period'}, $curr_part).'") div 1))';
            syslog(LOG_DEBUG, $query);
            $dbh->do($query);
        }
    }
}

sub remove_old_partitions {
    my $table_name = shift;
    my $table_part = shift;
    my $period = shift;
    my $keep_history = shift;

    my $curr_date = DateTime->now;
    $curr_date->set_time_zone( $curr_tz );

    if ( $period eq 'day' ) {
        $curr_date->add(days => -$keep_history);
        $curr_date->add(hours => -$curr_date->strftime('%H'));
        $curr_date->add(minutes => -$curr_date->strftime('%M'));
        $curr_date->add(seconds => -$curr_date->strftime('%S'));
    }
    elsif ( $period eq 'week' ) {
    }
    elsif ( $period eq 'month' ) {
        $curr_date->add(months => -$keep_history);

        $curr_date->add(days => -$curr_date->strftime('%d')+1);
        $curr_date->add(hours => -$curr_date->strftime('%H'));
        $curr_date->add(minutes => -$curr_date->strftime('%M'));
        $curr_date->add(seconds => -$curr_date->strftime('%S'));
    }

    foreach my $partition (sort keys %{$table_part}) {
        if ($table_part->{$partition}->{'partition_description'} <= $curr_date->epoch) {
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "Removing old $partition partition from $table_name table");

            my $query = "ALTER TABLE $db_schema.$table_name DROP PARTITION $partition";

            syslog(LOG_DEBUG, $query);
            $dbh->do($query);
        }
    }
}

sub name_next_part {
    my $period = shift;
    my $curr_part = shift;

    my $name_template;

    my $curr_date = DateTime->now;
    $curr_date->set_time_zone( $curr_tz );

    if ( $period eq 'day' ) {
        my $curr_date = $curr_date->truncate( to => 'day' );
        $curr_date->add(days => 1 + $curr_part);

        $name_template = $curr_date->strftime('p%Y_%m_%d');
    }
    elsif ($period eq 'week') {
        my $curr_date = $curr_date->truncate( to => 'week' );
        $curr_date->add(days => 7 * $curr_part);

        $name_template = $curr_date->strftime('p%Y_%m_w%W');
    }
    elsif ($period eq 'month') {
        my $curr_date = $curr_date->truncate( to => 'month' );
        $curr_date->add(months => 1 + $curr_part);

        $name_template = $curr_date->strftime('p%Y_%m');
    }

    return $name_template;
}

sub date_next_part {
    my $period = shift;
    my $curr_part = shift;

    my $period_date;

    my $curr_date = DateTime->now;
    $curr_date->set_time_zone( $curr_tz );

    if ( $period eq 'day' ) {
        my $curr_date = $curr_date->truncate( to => 'day' );
        $curr_date->add(days => 2 + $curr_part);
        $period_date = $curr_date->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
    }
    elsif ($period eq 'week') {
        my $curr_date = $curr_date->truncate( to => 'week' );
        $curr_date->add(days => 7 * $curr_part + 1);
        $period_date = $curr_date->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
    }
    elsif ($period eq 'month') {
        my $curr_date = $curr_date->truncate( to => 'month' );
        $curr_date->add(months => 2 + $curr_part);

        $period_date = $curr_date->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
    }

    return $period_date;
}

sub delete_old_data {
    $dbh->do("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE lastaccess < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");
    $dbh->do("TRUNCATE housekeeper");
    $dbh->do("DELETE FROM auditlog_details WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM auditlog WHERE auditlog.auditid = auditlog_details.auditid)");
}
```

and i did add some tunes to my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M # take ~75% of total available memory, for example if you have 8GB of RAM then set it to 6G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
query_cache_type = 0
innodb_io_capacity = 2000 #or 3000 in SSD scenario
```

i did install all the necessary packages fro the script like the syslog and DateTime and it's connection and accessing the database but the problem is when it tried to make partitions 
ps : partitioning for mariadb is enabled and i did it with and internal script and it worked fine

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward: the script can only add partitions if your table is partitioned to begin with, and it seems at least one table isn't. I am not familiar with zabbix, so I don't know if it e.g. should be by default though. I added "zabbix" to the tags, otherwise users familiar with zabbix (that might know the answer) might not see this question. Or with this background you might find something in the manual (or on stackoverflow), maybe https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/mysql_partition, not sure if if is applicable for you or if you e.g. did that already.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it worked ! i added a partition and then execute the script and it worked fine